# How does one wrap errors when calling COM in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, com, error-handling

To follow typical COM procedure, whenever any error occurs, one must do the following:

1. Check the `HRESULT` with `FAILED` or similar, to see if an error occured.
2. Create a variable to hold an `IErrorInfo` (typically `CComPtr<IErrorInfo>`)
3. Call `::GetErrorInfo(0, &var)`.
4. [Get the human readable version of that by calling `IErrorInfo::GetDescription`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597932/how-can-i-is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-hresult-into-a-system-specific-error-me)
5. Convert the `BSTR` into a `std::wstring`.
6. Convert the `std::wstring` into some form of `char const*`.
7. Throw a user defined exception type which derives from `std::exception` which exposes bits 1, 5, and 6 above.

This all seems like a lot of boilerplate which has to go around pretty much every function call in COM.

I know the MSVC++ compiler provides a whole bunch of stuff to make messing with COM easier, such as ATL, and the compiler specific COM extensions `_com_error`, `_com_raise_error` and similar, but I'm not sure how to use these, or if they're even intended to be used by user code.

Are there any typical strategies that are used to manage this complexity in an exception safe and race condition safe manner?

Comment: Start with the #import directive, the rest falls into place automatically.

Comment: @HansPassant: I don't have the type library for the target in question. (All I have is `wbemidl.h`)

Comment: Then fuggedaboudid, you have to wrap it yourself.  Just write a CheckHR() function.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes, I can wrap this myself without too much in terms of effort; but if there's already a semistandard method of doing this among people who use lots of COM I wanted to do it the typical way rather then inventing new stuff.

Comment: Why step 6? `std::exception` doesn't demand a `const char*`.

Comment: Step 2 is more complex than that actually.

Comment: @MSalters: You need a `const char*` to implement `std::exception::what`.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Care to enlighten me? Perhaps I misunderstood about this aspect of COM.

Comment: @BillyONeal: True, but that's a virtual function. You can move steps 2..6 to the override of `what()` in your own class. And if you don't call it (but instead add your own `wwhat()`), you'll never convert to `const char*`. Remember, the goal is human-readable, and there are billions of people who cannot read 8 bits text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "obvious" solution is a `ComException`. It can handle pretty much all steps - you just need to get obtain the `HRESULT` for the ctor and throw the resulting object (steps 1 and 7).

You can even write

```
HRESULT check(HRESULT hr)
{
  if(FAILED(hr)) throw ComException(hr);
  return hr; // Success comes in different forms. 
}
```

to take care of step 7 for you. E.g. `check(pUnk->QueryInterface(MyID, &pMyIf));`

Comment: @AlexandreC. : That would happen in `ComException::ComException(HRESULT)`.

Comment: How does ComException retrieves the pointer to IErrorInfo ? You have to somehow pass to it a pointer to the interface you were calling the function from in the first place, no ?

Comment: @AlexandreC. : No, [that's done via `::GetErrorInfo`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4597974/15416)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no semi-standard way that is provided for you, even if you look at the sample apps and api usage on msdn they all show you have to manually do all the tedious HResult checking, checking if the IPtr is valid etc.. You will have to write your own function that wraps all of this so that you do not duplicate code, it shouldn't be a problem.