# Turning HResult into actual errorcode, Delphi

Tags: delphi, exception

At a certain moment an EOleSysError occurs and the errorcode of that exception is an HRESULT.
Is there a way where I can turn that HResult back into an errorcode or string?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? The `HRESULT` is the error code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A HRESULT already is an error code. Its meaning depends on the call that was made. In COM, HRESULTs are returned, because exceptions are not allowed. To work around that, it is common to call `OleCheck`, which checks a HRESULT and raises and exception if it is a value other than `S_OK`. That is the EOleSysError you are getting. :)

Note however, that HRESULT is already an error code. HRESULT is just an integer. The name is misleading, because the `H` suggests it is a handle, but it is not.

So there isn't any more information than you have now. The HRESULT value, combined with the documentation of the API you are calling, should give you all the details you need.

Comment: Not much point calling `OleCheck` since we already have an `EOleSysError`. It would appear that somebody already did that!

Comment: the error occurs when the application tries to make a connection with outlook when there is no outlook found or installend on the computer.  but does this mean that the errorcode is always the same on a different computer?

Comment: Yes, if the same error occurs this should result in the same HRESULT. Like I said, it's an actual error code, not a handle.

Comment: And `HRESULT` is a structured value. It is made up of different components. It can be decoded. Some relevant articles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597932/how-can-i-is-there-a-way-to-convert-an-hresult-into-a-system-specific-error-me  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/03/942851.aspx?PageIndex=2

Comment: yes that why I thought I needed to break the HRESULT back apart to be sure I would catch the same error everytime, but no need if the errorcode stays the same.  Thanks guys!

Comment: It's perfectly plausible that there are other errors codes that would be returned for different but similar failures. Extremely hard to predict.

Comment: For those intrested,  what I did now was   SendDebug(IntToStr(HResultCode(EOleSysError(E).ErrorCode)));    wich gave me error 499.                                          and that turned out to be an CO_E_CLASSSTRING.                    So now I use:                                                      if (E is EOleSysError) and                        (EOleSysError(E).ErrorCode = CO_E_CLASSSTRING) then ...         Works like a charm :D